# Calling a Python Script from Jenkins Pipeline DSL causing import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dsl

Code:
sh 'python ./selenium/xy_python/run_tests.py'

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./selenium/xy_python/run_tests.py", line 6, in 
    import nose
ImportError: No module named nose

Answer (score 0):

Does it run successfully if you start it manually? If yes, then you might have problems with PYTHONPATH. You can use withEnv to set it.

```
withEnv(['PYTHONPATH=/your/pythonpath']) {
    sh  'python ./selenium/xy_python/run_tests.py'
}
```

Comment: the [ is not closed is it intentional ? It's giving me error "syntax error near unexpected token"

Comment: Yep, I have forgotten closing ].

Answer (score 0):

I recommend explicitly activating a python env before you run your script in your jenkinsfile to ensure you are in an environment which has nose installed.

Please check out virtualenv, tox, or conda for information on how to do so.